# How to hide 'Submit for Review' button for a specific role in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Currently, I've got 2 roles which are Contributor and Editor, both of these roles are able to submit for review, but I only want Editor has this button and hide it for Contributor.

Comment: I would just do it in css or js. In css I'll hide that section and in js I'll hide and add a disabled attribute to button. Enqueue your script in admin_enqueue_scripts() before you enqueue, add a check if the user is editor or contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide it for a specific role you can wrap it in an if condition using current_user_can()

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') ) {  ?> 
    // code here for the editor
<?php } ?>
```